# Why does a type hint `float` accept `int` while it is not even a subclass?

Tags: python, unions, type-hinting

On the one hand, I have learned that numbers that can be `int` or `float` should be type annotated as `float` (sources: [PEP 484 Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928592/mypy-type-hint-unionfloat-int-is-there-a-number-type/50928627)):

```py
def add(a: float, b: float):
    return a + b
```

On the other hand, an `int` is not an instance of `float`:

- `issubclass(int, float)` returns `False`
- `isinstance(42, float)` returns `False`

I would thus have expected `Union[int, float]` to be the correct annotation for this use case.

**Questions:**

- What is the reason for that counter-intuitive behaviour? Does type hinting follow different mechanics than class comparisons (for instance in some case a "lossless casting" rule or so)?
- Are `int`/`float` a special case in type annotations? Are there other examples like this?
- Is there any linter that would warn me about `Union[float, int]` if this is an unintended use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> - Are int/float a special case in type annotations?

`float` is a special case.  `int` is not.  PEP 484 says, in the paragraph below the one referenced by the link in your question:

> when an argument is annotated as having type `float`, an argument of type `int` is acceptable;

So accepting `int` where `float` is annotated is explicitly a special case, independent of the way annotations generally deal with a class hierarchy.

> Are there other examples like this?

Yes, there's at least one other special case.  In that same paragraph PEP 484 goes on to say:

> for an argument annotated as having type `complex`, arguments of type `float` or `int` are acceptable.

> - Is there any linter that would warn me about `Union[float, int]` if this is an unintended use?

`Union[float, int]` is perfectly fine.

The special treatment of a `float` annotation is just a convenience (PEP 484 calls it a "shortcut") to allow people to avoid writing out the long-winded `Union[float, int]` annotation, because arguments that can be a `float` or an `int` are very common.

Comment: Yes pythons type annotations do make pragmatic compromises. Another example is annotating with `None` when it should be `NoneType` or something

Comment: Thanks! So my fallacy lies in the assumption that `float` should be preferred over `Union[int, float]`. It is totally fine that I use the more explicit `Union[int, float]` - right? :)