# Python Doc Function Parameters as int or float

Tags: python, parameters, documentation

For example in this function I want to say that `x` and `y` are numbers. They can be either an `int` or `float`

```
    def multiply(x: int, y: float):
        result = x * y
        return result
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: so in the code x is int and y is float. Can I say x  is int OR float

Comment: yes, you can `def multiply(x: int or float, y: float or int):`

Comment: oh, maybe then is in my IDE (vscode) that just shows the first option! I had tried that xD

Thanks people

Comment: You should have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928592/mypy-type-hint-unionfloat-int-is-there-a-number-type

Comment: @dimay That’s not how that works!