# if-elif-else Statement - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

Beginner here! Been racking my brain over this Python test question for two days...Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks :)

Tried about a dozen versions, but here's where I feel I'm closest:

=======================

```
def exam_grade(score):
    if exam_grade(score) >= 96:
        grade = "Top Score"
    elif exam_grade(score) >= 60 and <=95:
        grade = "Pass"
    else:
        grade = "Fail"
    return grade


print(exam_grade(65)) # Should print Pass
print(exam_grade(55)) # Should print Fail
print(exam_grade(60)) # Should print Pass
print(exam_grade(95)) # Should print Pass
print(exam_grade(100)) # Should print Top Score
print(exam_grade(0)) # Should print Fail
```

=======================

*It seems like no matter what I tweak, I get syntax errors on >, <, <=, >=, or some end line character. :/

Comment: This doesn't work in python `exam_grade(score) >= 60 and <=95` you need `exam_grade(score) >= 60 and exam_grade(score) <=95` or similar. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al

Comment: The problem is not the `elif`, the problem is that `and` doesn't work that way.  You need `elif grade >= 60 and grade <= 95:` or `elif 60 <= grade <= 95:`.  BTW, don't call `exam_grade` recursively; inside the function, just use `grade`.

Comment: @TimRoberts `score`, not `grade` :)

Comment: why is the recursive call inside the func? like `elif exam_grade(...)`? It make no sense to me. remove the recursive call with `exam_grade` - this is not good use case for it.

Comment: score is the num, so type annotate for clarity: `score: float | int`. you don't need to recurse into func at all. you got the equality check vastly down, just need to tweak it a bit is all.

Comment: FWIW @rv.kvetch you don't need `float | int` — `float` is enough as [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower) points out. See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928592/mypy-type-hint-unionfloat-int-is-there-a-number-type)

Comment: @Mark Interesting - now I'll have to say TIL. Thanks for sharing ;)

Comment: Appreciate the help everyone :)