# Python type hints for type promotion

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Consider a function that performs type promotion, e.g. a simple multiplication of two numbers that can both be either `int` or `float`:

```py
def mul(a: int | float, b: int | float):  # return type?
    return a * b
```

This function returns `float`, except in the case where both `a` and `b` are `int`.

How can I properly and concisely annotate the return type? I know I can do this with `@overload`:

```py
from typing import overload

@overload
def mul(a: int, b: int) -> int: ...

@overload
def mul(a: float, b: int | float) -> float: ...

@overload
def mul(a: int | float, b: float) -> float: ...

def mul(a, b):
    return a * b
```

but this is very verbose and requires many overloads for something I would imagine some "type function" should handle. In C++ this could be done e.g. with [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). Is there something similar I can do in Python in terms of a generic function along the lines of

```py
def mul(a: T1, b: T2) -> promote_types(T1, T2):
    return a * b
```

that also works with TypeVars? I don't expect anything built in that already works for `int` and `float`, but some technique perhaps?

Notes:

- I know about the recommendation to just annotate everything taking an `int` with `float`, but my setting has more complicated TypeVars, the choice of `int` and `float` here is just a simple example.
- I know I can just do `Union[int, float]`, but I need it to be specific. Depending on the exact types the function is called with, the return type must be exact too, not a union.

Comment: [mypy, type hint: Union\[float, int\] -> is there a Number type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68053009)

Comment: It needs to be specific, a Union won't do unfortunately.

Comment: The result type is not merely dependent on types of arguments, but in particular, on the operation applied. In this case, it's dependent on `__mul__` or `__rmul__` implementation.

Comment: Is [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=ebd36b6bafe0e2a9decf24d67c9fb176) what you’re looking for? (Ignore the error for now)

Comment: Do you mean specifically float and int or some other types as well? It's important, because `int` is a subtype of `float` in python (but not subclass), so such "promotion" can happen during TypeVar resolution as @dROOOze shows, but if you need something like `np.uint8` - it's a totally different story not doable in pure python types, you'll need a `mypy` plugin.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about that implicit `int -> float` promotion during TypeVar resolution. It seems I have to read up about the difference between subtypes and subclasses and how they are handled in Python. That fact indeed solves one particular problem of mine. However I would also like to know for the general case, i.e. general types `A` and `B` that are not `int` and `float`. @STerliakov could you point me towards that mypy plugin?

Comment: This is a great question - I've faced this quite a bit, and it gets worse the more arguments you add - e.g. with 3 args the number of overloads increases to be quite daft

Comment: The other use case I've had this issue is numpy arrays - e.g. two args can be both array and float let's say - `float*float = float`, `float*Array = Array` & `Array*Array=Array`. Only way to solve this is with a lot of overloads

Comment: I didn't mean that such plugin exists, you'll have to write one. Numpy `mypy` plugin doesn't do this AFAIC, it only assigns platform-dependent number precision.

Comment: aha I see @STerliakov I misunderstood your comment then :-)

Comment: I don't quite understand the example of "general types `A` and `B`". Does C++ allow you to "promote" an instance of an arbitrary class `A` into another arbitrary class `B`, where `A` and `B` don't have a parent-child relationship? I always thought that the type information at a C++ function definition will help choose the appropriate constructor if you wanted to do some kind of casting (`void f(A a);` `B b;` then calling `f(b)` will choose a constructor on `A` which accepts an instance of `b`). If you're looking for this, then Python doesn't support it.

Comment: In C++ you can do this with static members of struct templates as template parameters (let this sink for a while). It is a bit verbose and cryptic at first but I actually find it quite elegant. Type promotion can e.g. be done with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type or you can implement your own rules using a struct template that has or doesn't have the value member variable for each template specialization (each specialization defines a rule)