# Are type vars and type unions incompatible in python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, pyright, type-variables

Consider the following snippet:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

import numpy as np

T = TypeVar("T", float, np.ndarray)


def f(x: T) -> T:
    """
    expects a float or an array and returns an output of the same type
    """
    return x * 2


f(1)  # ok

f(np.array([1, 2, 3]))  # ok


def g(x: float | np.ndarray) -> float | np.ndarray:
    """
    expects either a float or an array
    """
    return f(x) / 2  # should be fine, but pyright complains about type
```

I have created a TypeVar to hint that `f` expects as input a float or an array and will return an output of the same type.

The type hint in `g` is more loose. It expects either a float or an array and will return a float or an array, without constraining the type of the output to the type of the input.

Intuitively, the setup makes sense. Inside the definition of the `g` function we know that we expect `x` to be either a float or an array, i.e. what `f` expects as input. However when I pass `x` to `f` at the last line, Pyright complains:

> Argument of type "float | ndarray[Unknown, Unknown]" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "T@f" in function "f"
>
> Type "float | ndarray[Unknown, Unknown]" is incompatible with constrained type variable "T"

This is surprising and frustrating, because it means that one cannot use my function `f` without being very cautious about the way they write their type hints.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

**Edit**:
After the comment of Brian61354270, I have recreated essentially the same example, only with no dependence of numpy. Here instead of numpy array we use `Fraction`:

```py
from fractions import Fraction
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", float, Fraction)


def f(x: T) -> T:
    """
    expects a float or a Fraction and returns an output of the same type
    """
    return x * 2


f(1.0)  # ok

f(Fraction(1, 2))  # ok


def g(x: float | Fraction) -> float | Fraction:
    """
    expects either a float or a Fraction
    """
    return f(x) / 2  # should be fine, but pyright complains about type
```

Again, Pyright reports essentially the same issue:

> Argument of type "float | Fraction" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "T@f" in function "f"
>
> Type "float | Fraction" is incompatible with constrained type variable "T"

Interestingly, if instead of `Fraction` we use `int`, the type check passes:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", float, int)


def f(x: T) -> T:
    """
    expects a float or an integer and returns an output of the same type
    """
    return x * 2


f(1.0)  # ok

f(1)  # ok


def g(x: float | int) -> float | int:
    """
    expects either a float or an integer
    """
    return f(x) / 2  # now its ok
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does mypy say the same thing?

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні mypy gives the error `error: Value of type variable "T" of "f" cannot be "float | ndarray[Any, Any]"`, as well as some errors due to missing type parameters on `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Can you reproduce this error using an example that doesn't involve `numpy`? Using `numpy` prevents people from using online type checkers like https://pyright-play.net or https://mypy-play.net

Comment: re: _"Interestingly, if instead of Fraction we use int, the type check passes:"_, see [PEP 484 - The Numeric Tower](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50928627/11082165)

Comment: @Brian61354270. Thanks for this comment. You taught me something new today. I guess this remark is not that interesting after all. Do you think I should remove it, or should I leave it there for future reference?

Answer (score 2):

> Are type vars and type unions incompatible in python?

This isn't the issue. The type variable defined, `T = TypeVar("T", float, Fraction)`, is [*constrained*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound) to `float` or `Fraction`. `f(x: T)` can only accept an instance of `float` or `Fraction`, not the union `float | Fraction`. Your example can be reduced to the following ([Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAqiApgGoCGIAUKJFKOQMYxJgoDOm2u%2BAYiExZsqVAlAC8hEhRAAKAEQF5AGnoAbMORir%2Bg1igCUIgCbFg9WQA8AXIQNQAtAD5CtgHQeqp82mIxeGloA8iC6zPqy9s7qmvgAPlBhQijunjSyAIxuAAz2UADEUGAA1ulJERmqAEwGeYUlVCgArhC2wIHxiQLhbBJQvv4dIeVskenNEEZAA), [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=e7a168a7cfd6f3314d97a1eda080044b))

```py
from typing import TypeVar
from fractions import Fraction

T = TypeVar("T", float, Fraction)

def f(x: T) -> T: ...
def getFloatOrFraction() -> float | Fraction: ...
```

```
>>> f(1.0)  # ok
>>> f(Fraction(1, 2))  # ok
>>> num: float | Fraction = getFloatOrFraction()
>>> f(num)  # Error
```

I don't exactly know what your `f` and `g` needs, but

- If you still require type constraints (e.g. if all the inferred return type of `f` should be upcasted to exactly one of `float`, `Fraction`, or `float | Fraction`), you'll need to add the union as an additional constraint:

  ```py
  T = TypeVar("T", float, Fraction, float | Fraction)

  class MyFloat(float): ...

  def getMyFloatOrFraction() -> MyFloat | Fraction: ...
  ```

  ```
  >>> reveal_type(f(getMyFloatOrFraction()))  # float | Fraction
  ```
- If you don't require type constraints, then setting an upper bound is easier:

  ```py
  T = TypeVar("T", bound=float | Fraction)

  class MyFloat(float): ...

  def getMyFloatOrFraction() -> MyFloat | Fraction: ...
  ```

  ```
  >>> reveal_type(f(getMyFloatOrFraction()))  # MyFloat | Fraction
  ```

Answer (score 0):

While not a desirable solution, you can resolve this error by repeating the call to `f` in `g` under explicit type guards:

```
def g(x: float | np.ndarray) -> float | np.ndarray:
    """
    expects either a float or an array
    """
    if isinstance(x, (float, int)):
        return f(x) / 2
    return f(x) / 2
```

Output using pyright v1.1.329:

```
0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations
```

Comment: Nice catch. However this is really contrived and I don't think its an acceptable solution. Imagine working really hard to write good type hints for your library only to force your users to write code like this! This would be a disaster. I thought type hits were there to help us write cleaner code, but I am afraid they are beginning to enforce weird coding patterns, only to trick the type checker into passing the test.